# Memory stream is not expandable

Tags: c#, email, stream

I'm attempting to read an email attachment and I'm getting a "Memory Stream is not expandable" error. I researched this some and most of the solutions seemed related to determining the size of the buffer dynamically, but I'm already doing that.  I'm not very experienced with memory streams, so I'd like to know WHY this is a problem.  Thanks.

```
foreach (MailMessage m in messages)
{
   byte[] myBuffer = null;
   if (m.Attachments.Count > 0)
   {
      //myBuffer = new byte[25 * 1024];  old way 
      myBuffer = new byte[m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];
      int read;
      while ((read = m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Read(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
          // error occurs on executing next statement
          m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Write(myBuffer, 0, read);
      }

      ... more unrelated code ...
```

Comment: If the purpose of your stream is to read the attachment, why does the line you highlighted **write** to it?

Comment: This snippet is part of a larger process that reads the attachment into a buffer and then passes the buffer (and the xmlDocument that is in the body of the email) to another process. I highlighted the line that was generating the exception.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you create a MemoryStream over a pre-allocated byte array, it can't expand (ie. get longer than the size you specified when you started). Instead, why not just use:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   // Do your thing, for example:
   m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);

   return ms.ToArray(); // This gives you the byte array you want.
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the key is to use the empty (no params) `MemoryStream()` ctor, which creates it as expandable.

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace the line

```
m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Write(myBuffer, 0, read);
```

with a line that writes to a previously created `MemoryStream`, e.g.

```
foreach (MailMessage m in messages)
{
   byte[] myBuffer = null;
   if (m.Attachments.Count > 0)
   {
      //myBuffer = new byte[25 * 1024];  old way 
      myBuffer = new byte[m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Length];
      int read;
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      while ((read = m.Attachments[0].ContentStream.Read(myBuffer, 0, myBuffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
          ms.Write(myBuffer, 0, read);
      }
```