# Unable to save changes to XML document stored in Sharepoint 2010 Document Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a project that requires all SQL connection and query information to be stored in XML files. To make my project configurable, I am trying to create a means to let the user configure his sql connection string information (datasource, catalog, username and password) via a series of text boxes. This input will then be saved to the appropriate node within the SQL document.

I can get the current information from the XML file, and display that information within text boxes for the user's review and correction, but I'm encountering an error when it comes time to save the changes.

Here is the code I'm using to update and save the xml document.

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPFile file = methods.web.GetFile("MyXMLFile.xml");
        myDoc = new XmlDocument();
        byte[] bites = file.OpenBinary();
        Stream strm1 = new MemoryStream(bites);
        myDoc.Load(strm1);

        XmlNode node;
        node = myDoc.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode node1 in node.ChildNodes)
        {
           foreach (XmlNode node2 in node1.ChildNodes)
           {
               if (node2.Name == "name1")
               {
                   if (node2.InnerText != box1.Text)
                   {

                   }
               }

               if (node2.Name == "name2")
               {
                   if (node2.InnerText != box2.Text)
                   {

                   }
               }

               if (node2.Name == "name3")
               {
                   if (node2.InnerText != box3.Text)
                   {
                       node2.InnerText = box3.Text;
                   }
               }

               if (node2.Name == "name4")
               {
                   if (node2.InnerText != box4.Text)
                   {

                   }
               }
           }
        } 

        myDoc.Save(strm1);
    }
```

Most of the conditionals are empty at this point because I'm still testing.

The code works great until the last line, as I said. At that point, I get the error "Memory Stream is not expandable." I understand that using a memory stream to update a stored file is incorrect, but I can't figure out the right way to do this.

I've tried to implement the solution given in the similar question at [Memory stream is not expandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422803/memory-stream-is-not-expandable) but that situation is different from mine and so the implementation makes no sense to me. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `MemoryStream` constructor that takes a byte array as an argument creates a non-resizable instance of a `MemoryStream`. Since you are making changes to the file (and therefore the underlying bytes), you need a resizable `MemoryStream`. This can be accomplished by using the parameterless constructor of the `MemoryStream` class and writing the byte array into the `MemoryStream`.

Try this:

```
    SPFile file = methods.web.GetFile("MyXMLFile.xml");
    myDoc = new XmlDocument();
    byte[] bites = file.OpenBinary();

    using(MemoryStream strm1 = new MemoryStream()){
         strm1.Write(bites, 0, (int)bites.Length);
         strm1.Position = 0;
         myDoc.Load(strm1);

         // all of your edits to the file here
         strm1.Position = 0;

         // save the file back to disk
         using(var fs = new FileStream("FILEPATH",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite)){
              myDoc.Save(fs);
         }
    }
```

To get the `FILEPATH` for a Sharepoint file, it'd be something along these lines (I don't have a Sharepoint development environment set up right now):

```
SPFile file = methods.web.GetFile("MyXMLFile.xml")
var filepath = file.ParentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "\\" + file.Name;
```

Or it might be easier to just use the `SaveBinary` method of the `SPFile` class like this:

```
  // same code from above

  // all of your edits to the file here
  strm1.Position = 0;
  // don't use a FileStream, just SaveBinary
  file.SaveBinary(strm1);
```

I didn't test this code, but I've used it in Sharepoint solutions to modify XML (mainly OpenXML) documents in Sharepoint lists. Read [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/12/10/working-with-in-memory-open-xml-documents.aspx) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the response, rwisch. Unfortunately, this code throws an error at the line "myDoc.Load(strm1)" which says "XmlException was unhandled by user code: Root Element is missing." I checked out that blog post you linked to, but it's a bit different from what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to work with straight XML files, not Office documents. Sorry if I'm being thick, but I don't see the connection.

Comment: Update: found out this error means the xml document's root node is missing, but I have one. I even ran my xml through the w3schools validator and confirmed it's good xml. So what gives?

Comment: Update 2: For giggles, I tried removing the ? marks from the <?xml declaration so I would have to use an explicit </xml> closting tag. No change

Comment: @bmurrell30 Sorry - you have to reset the position of the `MemoryStream` after writing the bytes to it. You can do it with `strm1.Position=0` - I updated the code

Comment: I tried your updated code, and it will get through the method without throwing an error now, but the changes aren't being saved back to the file in the document library. Any other ideas?

Comment: Update: Tried adding "file.Update();" after the line "myDoc.Save(strm1);", thinking that might be what's needed to push the changes to the file in the doc library. no dice; changes still aren't taking.

Comment: @bmurrell30 I just updated the code in my post. Previously, we were just making the xml changes within the context of the `MemoryStream` *but* we weren't persisting them back to disk. Use a `FileStream` or the `SaveBinary` method to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the XDocument class instead of XmlDocument class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

I prefer it because of the simplicity and it eliminates having to use Memory Stream.

**Edit**: You can append to the file like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load('filePath');
                doc.Root.Add(
                    new XElement("An Element Name",
                        new XAttribute("An Attribute", "Some Value"),
                        new XElement("Nested Element", "Inner Text"))
                    );
                doc.Save(filePath);
```

Or you can search for an element and update like this:

```
doc.Root.Elements("The element").First(m => 
     m.Attribute("An Attribute").Value == "Some value to match").SetElementValue(
          "The element to change", "Value to set element to");
doc.Save('filePath');
```

Comment: Please demonstrate how I would use XDocument in this case. I've been through the msdn page you linked to; I've tried loading my xml straight into the XDocument object, I've tried loading it into an XmlReader object (to be loaded into the XDocument afterwards), and I've tried the WebClient StreamReader example shown at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19753.read-xml-file-from-document-library-all-sharepoint-version.aspx, and I keep getting the error "The best overloaded match for ... has some invalid arguments."