# How to fix Stream can not be expandable with Xml Serialization

Tags: c#

Memory stream can not be expanded exception thrown in Xml serialization with below code.

```
string message = string.Empty;

MyMessageTpe obj = new MyMessageTpe() 
{
   Age = 20 
};

XmlSerializer xmlSerialization = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyMessageTpe));

Stream str = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.UTF32.GetBytes(message));

TextWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(str);

xmlSerialization.Serialize(strWriter, obj);
```

Comment: By passing a byte array to the constructor of the `MemoryStream` you are creating a non-resizable stream that is the size of the array you passed in.  Since `message` is an empty string, your memory stream has a capacity of 0.  By the way, `ASCIIEncoding.UTF32` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=netframework-4.7.2) over a pre-allocated byte array, it can't expand. Just use without initializing its size.

```
string message = string.Empty;
MyMessageTpe obj = new MyMessageTpe() { Age = 20 };
XmlSerializer xmlSerialization = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyMessageTpe));
Stream str = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter strWriter = new StreamWriter(str);

xmlSerialization.Serialize(strWriter, obj);
```

[Memory stream is not expandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422803/memory-stream-is-not-expandable)

MemoryStream()
*Initializes a new instance of the MemoryStream class with an expandable capacity initialized to zero.*

MemoryStream(Byte[])
*Initializes a new non-resizable instance of the MemoryStream class based on the specified byte array.*