# Reading Request.Body stream and appending to another stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Using C#, .NET Core 3.1

I am creating an AuthorizationFilter and I am trying to read the request Body and write it to a new memory stream but it just dies on the line.

EDIT++ Thanks for the responses.  I didn't realise it was dumping the exception in Output: `System.NotSupportedException: Memory stream is not expandable.`

If I instantiate with new MemoryStream() only and no parameter, it works.

```
var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
request.EnableBuffering();


Stream stream= new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(someHash));

request.Body.Position = 0;
await using var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(requestHash));
stream.Position = stream.Length;
await request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
```

So I guess the issue is that I instantiated MemoryStream with someHash and it can no longer be expanded.  I guess I need to just create an empty stream and use copyToAsync() once for someHash and another time for request.Body content.

Comment: what is the exception? your code seems to overwrite the output stream, not appending.

Comment: Should it not be `OutStream.WriteAsync...`?

Comment: By the way, you can just use the `Stream.CopyToAsync` function and you done need the while loop.

Comment: @Magnus hi, do you mean like this await request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream); ?

Comment: have you even tried debugging it yet? if there is no exception, try taking a look into the Output window, the exception may be suppressed from being thrown while debugging but should always be printed out. For 2 normal streams the code seem to work fine, but there may be something special with `request.Body` so we need more info about the exception (which should be thrown per what you described).

Comment: Yes you have to work it around, building everything into a new empty MemoryStream (cannot instantiate it with some data and append more after that)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422803/memory-stream-is-not-expandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I instantiated MemoryStream with someHash and it can no longer be expanded. I guess I need to just create an empty stream and use copyToAsync() once for someHash and another time for request.Body content.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following code above your code:

```
 var syncIOFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBodyControlFeature>();
        if (syncIOFeature != null)
        {
            syncIOFeature.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        }
 //...your code.
```